# How to use "AND" in a Django filter?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm, django-filter

How do I create an "AND" filter to retrieve objects in Django? e.g I would like to retrieve a row which has a combination of two words in a single field.

For example the following SQL query does exactly that when I run it on mysql database:

```sql
SELECT * FROM myapp_question
WHERE ((question LIKE '%software%') AND (question LIKE '%java%'))
```

How do you accomplish this in Django using filters?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

(**update**: this answer will not work anymore and give the syntax error `keyword argument repeated`)

```
mymodel.objects.filter(first_name__icontains="Foo", first_name__icontains="Bar")
```

**update**: Long time since I wrote this answer and done some django, but I am sure to this days the best approach is to use the Q object method like David Berger shows here: [How do I use AND in a Django filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/770078/63097)

Comment: This does _not_ work for me in Django 1.6 and Postgres. I get a "SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated" whenever there are two or more the same keywords. Only the solution with Q by David Berger works.

Comment: @margusholland The answer works for me with Django 1.6 & Postgres. Can you post your query. It's as official as Q object method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: I have a model Country with a short country code field (cc_short): 

>>> countries = Country.objects.filter(cc_short__icontains='A', cc_short__icontains='B')
  File "<console>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

Comment: This also _does not_  work for me either. Same error as @margusholland. Using Django 1.7.5. Code in question: `talks = Talks.objects.filter(description__contains=topics,description__contains=terms).order_by('-datetime')` Topics and terms are both lists.

Comment: I am also getting the SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated coming if I fire the similar query. My query `media_house_writers = ScatterxBloggerProfile.objects.filter(level__icontains="media_house", level__icontains="publisher")`. Plz help.

Comment: Note that both fields are the same! It's python itself that doesn't allow this, it won't work in ANY django/db. This should not be an accepted answer.

Comment: Long time since I wrote this answer and done some django, but I am sure to this days the best approach is to use the Q object method like David Berger shows here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/770078/63097. 
Also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: @gath the accepted answer needs to be changed since this one would not work

Comment: @rsalmei will it work if both filter fields are different

Comment: Hey @MayankMehtani, it should work if the keyword arguments themselves are different, not only their values.

Comment: It is working for different fields only not the same field.

Answer (score 172):

For thoroughness sake, let's just mention the [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object method:

```
from django.db.models import Q
criterion1 = Q(question__contains="software")
criterion2 = Q(question__contains="java")
q = Question.objects.filter(criterion1 & criterion2)
```

Note the other answers here are simpler and better adapted for your use case, but if anyone with a similar but slightly more complex problem (such as needing "not" or "or") sees this, it's good to have the reference right here.

Comment: Just wanted to mention your passing comment helped me.  Thanks!

Comment: See here for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

Answer (score 18):

You can chain filter expressions in Django:

```
q = Question.objects.filter(question__contains='software').filter(question__contains='java')
```

You can find more info in the Django docs at "[Chaining Filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters)".

Comment: This answer may give you wrong results depending on your scenario. Using `,` in filter vs chaining filters can have different results. Further reading : [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11025652/781695) & [Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Comment: this is NOT answer for the asked question. It will give diff output. But this is what I was looking for. 
What OP wanted,  allobjects.filter(name=x or name= y) but this answer will give first = allobjects.filter(name=x) then filter first.filter(name=y). Hope you guys get it. Sorry for pseudo code.

Comment: @mohammed_ayaz The question asks for an AND operation, not an OR operation.

Comment: I am really curious why this answered was even upvoted. Besides the fact that this has an OR logic, it will have different results if the filtered fields are from referenced tables.

Comment: @Alexandru-MihaiManolescu: What has OR logic? This question is an AND, not an OR.

Comment: In `OneToMany` and `M2M` relations it should be used with caution, as it applies to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier `filter()` call.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`AND`** with [**filter()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) using **`&`** or [**Q()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and **`&`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Question
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "&"
                                                              # ↓ Here
    qs = Question.objects.filter(question__contains="software") & \ 
         Question.objects.filter(question__contains="java")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "&"
                               # ↓ Here                         # ↓ Here
    qs = Question.objects.filter(Q(question__contains="software") & 
                                 Q(question__contains="java"))
    print(qs)                  # ↑ Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```