# Django ManyToMany Relation "Contains" Statement

Tags: python, sql, django, database, orm

I am building a small Task Manager, all Tasks have Labels. I need to Select all tasks which have a few Labels. At the Moment, I am doing:

```
    tasks = Task.objects.all().filter(labels__in=label_list).distinct()
```

which returns all tasks, where at least one label is also in label_list, but I need only the Tasks that have all labels that are in label_list.

More precise example: If I pass by ['1', '2'] as label_list, I *don't* want all Tasks with either label 1 `OR` label 2 to be returned (that is what is happening now), but want all Tasks with Label 1 `AND` Label 2 to be returned.

I want the Tasks which Labels **contain** label list

The Relation Task-Label is ManyToMany:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ....
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Label, null=True, blank = True)
    ....
```

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270513/django-manytomany-filter-matching-on-all-items-in-a-list). The selected answer would work for you, and although hackish, it is quite creative.

Answer (score 1):

This is reaching the limits of django's ORM, but you could try:

```
labels = ['1', '2']
qs = Task.objects.all()
for label in labels:
    qs = qs.filter(labels=label).distinct()
```

Obviously pretty ugly, and it would be a pretty expensive operation for a long list of labels, but it might work to get you by.

Alternatively, you could check out [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) which is a mature django tagging application that provides similar 'label' functionality.  They handle the 'contains' issue by using raw SQL.