# Django - Greedy AND Query on ManyToMany

Tags: django, many-to-many

I've got a model that has a list of tags.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', max_length=150)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I want to be able to find all the Documents that are tagged with X and Y, but not exclusively X and Y. That is, I want documents that are tagged with X, Y, Z to show up when I search for X and Y.

The accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270513/django-manytomany-filter-matching-on-all-items-in-a-list) question gets me pretty far, but it returns items that are tagged with those and only those tags.  The annotation limits the query set.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  There's a great resource on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list).  In my particular case, I wanted chained filters.  This is how I did it with an arbitrary number of tags.

```
docs = Document.objects

for tag in tags:
    docs = docs.filter(tags=tag)
```

This gave me the AND query I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You simply want an `INNER JOIN` - which is the default when you filter across relations.

This should do what you want:

```
Document.objects.filter(tags=X, tags=Y)
```

This gets you each `Document` which has both tag X and tag Y, regardless of any other tags.

Comment: That won't work because the keyword argument is repeated.