# passing list of objects as manytomany field type in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to know if we can pass a list of objects (in this case list of blog objects to the Entry model as the manytomany object parameter). On doing so i am not getting the desired result. Please help.

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Entry(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blogs=models.ManyToManyField(Blog)
```

views.py

```
def something(request):
    list=[]
    for i in range(10):
        list.append(Blog.objects.get(pk=i))
    ans=Entry.objects.filter(blogs=list)
    print(ans)
    #some other work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you can do is replace your `for` iterator with this:

```
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(id__range=[0, 10])
```

Second, you can use the lookup feature using `__in`:

```
ans = Entry.objects.filter(blogs__in=blogs)
```

So your final `views.py` could look like this:

```
def something(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(id__range=[0, 10])
    ans = Entry.objects.filter(blogs__in=blogs)
    print(ans)
    #some other work.
```

Comment: This was helpful, but there is one more issue. when this list of blogs is being compared even if there is one object in the list that matches, it is being returned....i want to return only that object that matches the entire list or none at all.

Comment: Can you clarify that a bit more? I am having a hard time fully understanding the question

Comment: Actually I have a scenario in which I have multiple Blog objects that i dont know before hand...they could be as many. So i created a list of those objects and now i want to check if there exists some Entry object that contains all those blog objects.

Comment: I think I understand, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13275063/3345051 - it looks like that is the answer to your question, just replace the variable names. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you so much @Hybrid!!....I was stuck at this problem since yesterday!...you really helped me a lot :)