# Django query for vendors who supply all parts

Tags: django, django-models

Given the model (vendors supplying parts, many-to-many relation):

```
from django.db import models

class Part(models.Model):
    pass

class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

Is it possible to write a Django query to get vendors who supply all of the parts? I'm interested in a query which will produce single SQL statement.

---

For example, with the following data:

```
p1 = Part()
p2 = Part()
p3 = Part()
v1 = Vendor(name="supply nothing")
v2 = Vendor(name="supply some parts")
v3 = Vendor(name="supply all parts")
p1.save()
p2.save()
p3.save()
v1.save()
v2.save()
v3.save()
v2.parts.add(p1,p2)
v3.parts.add(p1,p2,p3)
```

I want to get:

```
[<Vendor: supply all parts>]
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270513/django-manytomany-filter-matching-on-all-items-in-a-list?answertab=votes#tab-top, sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks, but its not a single statement.

Comment: Well I'm not actually quite sure about the loop part in the answer I found, because I think the first part is enough. Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/sql-server-select-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list. Please try it out and see what's the difference before and after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could first query for all parts:

```
parts = Part.objects.all()
```

And then filter vendors:

```
vendors = Vendor.objects.filter(parts=parts)
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'part_set' into field. Choices are: id, name, parts`. I get the idea, but anyway this will produce two SQL queries, with list of parts traveling from and to database server. I'm looking for a single SQL statement solution.

Comment: @EgorRogov you have used a `related_name`, it is not in your question. I have edited my answer. Try it now

Comment: Nope, no related_name. Btw, updated version doesn't work too (`more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`).

Comment: @EgorRogov I have the exact structure here and it is working, what is your Django's version?

Comment: Models are exactly the same as described, I prepared them for this question. Database contains exactly the same data as described. There is nothing more.