# Django filtering by multiple tags in many to many ORM object

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, models

I have three models. `Query`, `QueryStringTag`, and `Tag`. These models are apart of a tag cloud that I have built. A `Query` can have many `Tag`s and a `Tag` can have many `Query`s. The `Tag` and `Query` models have foreign keys to the connecting `QueryStringTag` model that holds all of the information about how a query is associated with a tag and vice versa.

***Here are my models...***

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=101)
    use_count = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class QueryStringTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name='qstag')
    querystring = models.ForeignKey(QueryString, related_name='qsquerystring')

class QueryString(BaseObject): 
    """
    Query string holds an SQL statement and query properties for execution
    """

    server_id = models.IntegerField()
    schema = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    query = models.CharField(max_length=60000) 
    variables = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='queries_created')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='queries_last_edited')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    touched_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    config = models.TextField(blank=True)
    runs_started = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    runs_completed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    runs_completed_duration = models.IntegerField(default=0) # total number of seconds spent running this query to completion
    formats = "pretty_html html json prettyjson csv excel tableau".split()
```

I currently have it set up so a user clicks any given amount of tags in the tag cloud and an array of tag primary keys are sent down to my django view looking something like this: `['12', '14', '15']`

I need to use Django ORM to retrieve all queries that are associated with all of the tags the user clicked on. So if a user clicks on the tags, 'user', 'game', and 'truck' it should bring me back only the queries that are associated with all of the tags that the user clicked on. This is an `AND` relationship, not an `OR` relationship. Meaning "Query1" would be associated with '12' and '14' and '15'.

What would the correct syntax be for this?

Comment: It would be easier to implement this if you have `Tag` as `ManyToManyField` in `QuerySting`. What's the purpose for having `QueryStringTag`?

Comment: @ShangWang The long and short of it is that our local dev environment wont accept a `ManyToManyField`. I had to do it this way.

Comment: I've only done this with `ManyToManyField` and there are tons of answers related to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270513/django-manytomany-filter-matching-on-all-items-in-a-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list. Maybe raw sql would help.

Comment: @ShangWang This is a `ManyToManyField`, accept it is just spelled out. All the `ManyToManyField` does is make a center connecting table much like what I am doing.

Comment: Of course I'm aware of that. Maybe I'm missing something but my point is that your design makes it hard to do it using django ORM api. Although I still don't quite get what's blocking you from using `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: @ShangWang Trust me, man. If I could, I would. lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
qsts_pks = QueryStringTag.objects.filter(tag__pk__in=['12', '14', '15']).values_list('id', flat=True)
queries = QueryString.objects.filter(qsquerystring__pk__in=qsts_pks)
```

Relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)