# Querying a list to a manytomany field in django returning more results than expected

Tags: python, django

I wrote the following filter based off the answer provided here: [Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list/8637972#8637972)

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(entities__in=relevant_entities, alert_type=alert_type).annotate(num_entities=Count('entities')).filter(
        num_entities=len(relevant_entities))
```

The issue that I'm running into is that it seems to be filtering inappropriately, there are times where it's matching sublists, I was using get to get the distinct alert, but I noticed that some of them error out because they return multiple matches, and here's the culprit.

```
[2016-07-27 18:02:23,473: WARNING/Worker-4] [<Entity: DOGE>, <Entity: 8.8.8.8>]
[2016-07-27 18:02:23,474: WARNING/Worker-4] [<Entity: potato>, <Entity: DOGE>, <Entity: 8.8.8.8>]
[2016-07-27 18:02:23,475: WARNING/Worker-4] [<Entity: desktop_potato>, <Entity: DOGE>, <Entity: 8.8.8.8>]
```

My entities list should contain only

```
[<Entity: DOGE>, <Entity: 8.8.8.8>]
```

but it's somehow matching on the other two. Any help would be appreciated

The temporary hack that I came up with is this:

```
for alert in distinct_alert_query.all():
            if alert.entities.all().count() == len(relevant_entities) and all([entity in relevant_entities for entity in alert.entities.all()]):
                distinct_alert = alert
                break
```

where distinct_alert_query refers to the really long query mentioned above. The issue with this is that if the query's matching on Distinct_Alerts with a set of entities larger than relevant_entities it will break :(

models:

```
class Distinct_Alert(models.Model):
    #alert_type = models.ForeignKey(Alert_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE) for the sake of this problem and the filter, this isn't really needed. 
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(to='Entity', through='Entity_To_Alert_Map')

class Entity(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=700, blank=False)
    #entity_type = models.ForeignKey(Entity_Type_Label) not necessary for this problem
    related_entities = models.ManyToManyField('self')

class Entity_To_Alert_Map(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    distinct_alert = models.ForeignKey(Distinct_Alert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entity_alert_relationship_label = models.ForeignKey(Entity_Alert_Relationship_Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('entity', 'distinct_alert', 'entity_alert_relationship_label')
```

Comment: Show models, please.

Comment: @VladimirDanilov edited to include models.

Comment: @VladimirDanilov each distinct_alert has an entities field, that has a bunch of Entity objects.

Comment: You want to get `Distinct_Alert` objects with `entities` which are the same as `relevant_entities`, right?

Comment: @VladimirDanilov correct. With the caveat that there may be those Distinct_Alerts that may contain the same relevant entities + some other entities, in which case I do not want those distinct_alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Case, When, F

Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(
    alert_type=alert_type
).annotate(
    num_entities=Count('entities'),
    num_relevant_entities=Count(
        Case(When(entities__in=relevant_entities, then=1),
             default=None,
             output_field=IntegerField()),
    ),
).filter(
    num_entities=F('num_relevant_entities'),
    num_relevant_entities=len(relevant_entities),
)
```

Your query:

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(
    entities__in=relevant_entities,
    alert_type=alert_type
).annotate(
    num_entities=Count('entities')
).filter(
    num_entities=len(relevant_entities)
)
```

[Order of `annotate()` and `filter()` matters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses).

Comment: Hey Vladimir, this doesn't quite work for me, it doesn't seem to be filtering at all, in fact it's returning me over 300 Distinct_Alerts instead of the 3 that I got from before.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir! At first glance it seems to work like a charm. But my God this looks complicated. Again, thanks a bunch

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270513/django-manytomany-filter-matching-on-all-items-in-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1