# How to AND chain filters in a django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

[This question makes clear *how* chaining and multiple argument filters are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542874/difference-between-filter-with-multiple-arguments-and-chain-filter-in-django) but it doesn't specify how to make them chained filters equivalent.

For example, given the code:

```
query = mymodel.filter(name="Foo",foreignkey_property1="Bar",foreignkey_property2="Zap")
```

Is it possible to get an `and` version of this from a chained queryset and have the query above and the query below be equivalent:

```
query = mymodel.filter(name="Foo",foreignkey_property1="Bar")
query = query.filter(foreignkey_property2="Zap",???)
```

I'm certain I've read how this is possible, but can't find it.

Comment: Ah! Well, thats what my code is doing. How can I make them equivalent?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create separate [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) queries for `foreignkey_property1="Bar"` and `foreignkey_property2="Zap"` conditions and then combine them in a single `filter`?

Comment: Hmmm... I've rewritten this using Q()'s but I'd like to leave this open to see if there are other solutions in case someone doesnt have that luxury.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = mymodel.filter(Q(name="Foo",foreignkey_property1="Bar") && Q(foreignkey_property2="Zap"))
```

Comment: 'Q' module is used for doing conditional cases in filters

Comment: The double ampersand, `&&`, should probably be a single ampersand: `&`. As far as I know, `&&` is not a valid symbol in Python and results in a `SyntaxError`.