# How filter objects in django views?

Tags: django, filter, view

How can I filter two parameter in django views ?
for example my code is :

**Views : **

```
def products_filter(request, product, selling):
    all_product = Product.objects.filter(product=product).filter(selling=selling)
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? your code is viable, if you want just another variant, then you can use also Product.objects.filter(product=product, selling=selling)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
from django.db.models import Q

def products_filter(request, product, selling):
    all_product = Product.objects.filter(Q(product=product)| Q(selling=selling))
```

Comment: Can I use & symbol ?

Comment: I'm sorry, this question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542874/difference-between-filter-with-multiple-arguments-and-chain-filter-in-django