# How to perform a Django "AND" query with a Reverse ForeignKey or ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I found a different result on an "AND" query depending if it was a reverse of forward query.

1. In a **FORWARD** query you can do this:

```
Model.objects.filter(x=1) & Model.objects.filter(y=2)
Model.objects.filter(x=1, y=2)
Model.objects.filter(Q(x=1) & Q(y=2))
```

All give the same result: a QuerySet that satisfies both conditions (x=1 and y=2).

2. But If I have a **REVERSE FOREIGNKEY** or **MANY TO MANY**  “AND” query something different happens.

---

#### Explanation and code example.

I have these models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

And let's say I have this data:

| Headline | Pub Date Year | Authors | Blog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pop 1 | 2023 | Juan | Pop |
| Pop 2 | 2023 | Emma | Pop |
| Pop 3 | 2010 | Juan, Walmer | Pop |
| Other | 2023 | John | Beatles |

---

#### I want to make an “AND” query to get the authors that satisfy both the headline that contains the word “Pop” and Pub Date Year equal to 2023.

Expected result: Juan and Emma.

| Headline | Pub Date Year | Authors | Blog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pop 1 | 2023 | Juan | Pop |
| Pop 2 | 2023 | Emma | Pop |

We can use the following methods:

1. **Multiple Arguments within the filter.**

```
Author.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains="Pop", entry__pub_date__year=2023)
```

2. **Q object**

```
Author.objects.filter(Q(entry__headline__contains="Pop") & Q(entry__pub_date__year=2023))
```

--> These two give the same answer (the expected result: Juan and Emma) and create the same SQL:

```
SELECT  "blog_author"."id", "blog_author"."name", "blog_author"."email", "blog_author"."country_id" 

FROM "blog_author"

INNER JOIN "blog_entry_authors"

ON ("blog_author"."id" = "blog_entry_authors"."author_id")

INNER JOIN "blog_entry"

ON ("blog_entry_authors"."entry_id" = "blog_entry"."id")

WHERE ("blog_entry"."headline" LIKE %Pop% ESCAPE '\' AND "blog_entry"."pub_date" BETWEEN 2023-01-01 AND 2023-12-31)
```

#### HERE COMES THE PROBLEM

3. **With this third option the result is different. And I don't understand why.**

```
Author.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains="Pop") & Author.objects.filter(entry__pub_date__year=2023)
```

The result is different, the AND query gets this authors: Juan, Emma, Juan.
I thought this should also be: Juan and Emma.

But why it isn't?

This is the SQL created (which is different than the previous two)

```
SELECT "blog_author"."id", "blog_author"."name", "blog_author"."email", "blog_author"."country_id" 

FROM "blog_author"

INNER JOIN "blog_entry_authors"

ON ("blog_author"."id" = "blog_entry_authors"."author_id")

INNER JOIN "blog_entry"

ON ("blog_entry_authors"."entry_id" = "blog_entry"."id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "blog_entry_authors" T4

ON ("blog_author"."id" = T4."author_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "blog_entry" T5 ON (T4."entry_id" = T5."id")

WHERE ("blog_entry"."headline" LIKE %Pop% ESCAPE '\' AND T5."pub_date" BETWEEN 2023-01-01 AND 2023-12-31)
>>>
```

## **QUESTIONS:**

1. Why does the third option give a different result than the two previous ones?
2. Is this the expected result (Juan, Emma, Juan?)

Comment: Spanning multi-valued relationships: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: Thanks, but the official documentation says nothing about this specific question :(

Comment: The official documentation writes combine querysets must be same model for expected behaviour https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#operators-that-return-new-querysets

Comment: I think querysets combine using __and__() method. https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/query.py#L454

Comment: There is an answer that comments about this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65065813/6710903