# In Django, which has faster and better performance beween ".filter(a).filter(b)" and "Q objects" and "or/and queries" and "keyword queries"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Simply put, what is the order of performance and speed among the following similar looking queries in the Django ORM?

.filter(a).filter(b)

```
instances = Model.objects.filter(a=A).filter(b=B)
```

Q objects

```
instances = Model.objects.filter(Q(a=A) & Q(b=B))
```

or/and queries

```
instances = Model.objects.filter(a=A) & Model.objects.filter(b=B)
```

keyword queries

```
instances = Model.objects.filter(a=A, b=B)
```

AND please don't copy and paste chatgpt or any other ai services. Thank you, and please leave any comments below.

Comment: One filter with multiple constraints does not necessarily yield the same results as multiple filters with one constraint each. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542966/6890912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Django querysets [are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), there won't be any DB calls until you try to get data from it (e.g. `list(instances)`).
So if you created queryset and then added few more `.filter`'s, it will perform the same as if you created it at once.
If you don't use `Q` explicitly - Django uses it under the hood so there is no difference here as well.

In fact you can do `print(str(instances.query))` to see final query prepared by Django, and in our case all 4 queries are the same, so
**There is no difference in performance and speed at all**.

Answer (score 1):

The first aspect here is whether the these all produce *per se* the same query, and the same results. That is *not* the case for all queries.

Let us begin with two lines that *will* produce the same query:

```
instances = Model.objects.filter(Q(a=A) & Q(b=B))
instances = Model.objects.filter(a=A, b=B)
```

Indeed, both are equivalent, since the `.filter(..)` will construct a `Q` object based on what you pass. So both end up with a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM model
WHERE a = a AND b = b
```

so the exact query. Constructing the query with the ORM is only a matter of some text-processing that is resolved in *microseconds*, so that will not have much impact on the performance.

It is however a different story if you compare `Model.objects.filter(a=A, b=B)` and `Model.objects.filter(a=A).filter(b=B)` if `a` and `b` work with the same model. Indeed, the two consecutive [**`.filter(…)`** calls <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) will make *separate* joins, not work with the single one. This thus means that the *semantics* is different, you thus should not look at the performance but what your query is supposed to *do*, what items it should retrieve.

The same happens with `Model.objects.filter(a=A) & Model.objects.filter(b=B)`, here you thus make two queries you eventually intersect, but if the `a` and `b` are the same, it does not work like a `.filter(a=A, b=B)`.

Django does not do the filtering, it just constructs an SQL query to do that, and the database will then process the query. You thus should focus on *what* you aim to select, less *how* it is done.