# How to filter a Django query set by passing in a list of options?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got an abstract ProductAttribute model that can be associated with a Product model. The attributes can be accessed using product.attribute_values.

Say I've got a form which contains two select boxes that allow the user to specify the values of two attributes - Size and Weight.

How do I, in a single query, pass in those values into a filter, so that - as you can with a list of integers with `Object.objects.filter(pk__in=(1,2,3))` - I can select the Product that matches against all those attribute values?

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
options = ['XL','50lbs']
p = Product.objects.filter(attribute_values__matches=options)
```

Is this possible in a one-liner in Django?

TIA

Comment: Could you please show actual models?

Comment: I'm using the Oscar shopping cart framework, which abstracts out product attributes and options. Here are the docs, but I don't think that the actual models in this case will help: https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/blob/master/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py

Comment: What I'm really after is a generic way to pass in an AND filter for a given attribute into the queryset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or [`__exact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exact)

and for case insensitive matches [`__icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) and [`__iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact)

You can use `Q` model lookups to do an and filtering:

```
options = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3']
qs = [Q(attribute_name=option) for option in options] #or attribute_name__icontains - or whatever

query = qs.pop() #get the first element

for q in qs:
    query |= q

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: I think I just found this too, which should help: just chain the list into the query call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769843/how-do-i-use-and-in-a-django-filter

Comment: Thanks for the expansion with example. :)

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately in this case, this isn't quite working, since a ProductAttribute is a foreign key relationship to the Product. In other words, even though I can do product.attribute_values as a shortcut to get at a product's attributes, when I run the select query above, I get a "can't resolve 'attribute_values' into a field name. I suppose because I'd need to use some kind of select_related call on it? Any idea how I would iterate over the Products and their Attributes efficiently in a single query call, like you've started above?

Comment: since it is a reverse ForeignKey lookup, you can do `productattribute__attribute_name=whatever` (lowercase of model name)

Comment: This is still not solving the issue: I have a list of values for a set of attributes, and need to iterate over the collected set of attributes to match against the values. The error I get is "Cannot resolve keyword 'productattribute' into field. Choices are: attribute_values, attributes..." No "Product Attribute", which implies that I need to iterate over the attributes somehow to get at their values. Can you suggest a way? Sorry this is not all that clear. I am trying to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: OK, I've cracked it now. I will use a version of your code, and add in Q() statements, but I needed to use a complicated join: products = Product.objects.filter(attributes__name='Size').filter(attribute_values__value_option__option='XL')

Comment: What is this sorcery: `query |= q`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up cracking this one with a little help from @karthikr above, and the the Q.add() method:

```
options = {'Size':'XL'}
qs = Q()
for key, val in options.iteritems():
qs.add(Q(attributes__name=key) & Q(attribute_values__value_option__option=val), qs.connector)
```

Hope this helps someone else in some small way in future.