# Django ORM. Filter many to many with AND clause

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

With the following models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(ItemAttribute)


class ItemAttribute(models.Model):
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    string_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    int_value = models.IntegerField()
```

I also have an `Item` which has 2 attributes, `'color': 'red'`, and `'size': 3`.

If I do any of these queries:

```
Item.objects.filter(attributes__string_value='red')
Item.objects.filter(attributes__int_value=3)
```

I will get `Item` returned, works as I expected.

However, if I try to do a multiple query, like:

```
Item.objects.filter(attributes__string_value='red', attributes__int_value=3)
```

All I want to do is an AND. This won't work either:

```
Item.objects.filter(Q(attributes__string_value='red') & Q(attributes__int_value=3))
```

The output is:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Why? How can I build such a query that my `Item` is returned, because it has the attribute `red` and the attribute `3`?

Comment: Did you mean an "AND query"  when you said "multiple" ?

Comment: Yes, I want to do an `AND`.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769843/how-do-i-use-and-in-a-django-filter/770078#770078

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's of any use, you can chain filter expressions in Django:

```
query = Item.objects.filter(attributes__string_value='red').filter(attributes__int_value=3')
```

From the [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters):

> This takes the initial QuerySet of all entries in the database, adds a filter, then an exclusion, then another filter. The final result is a QuerySet containing all entries with a headline that starts with “What”, that were published between January 30, 2005, and the current day.

To do it with `.filter()` but with dynamic arguments:

```
args = {
    '{0}__{1}'.format('attributes', 'string_value'): 'red',
    '{0}__{1}'.format('attributes', 'int_value'): 3
}

Product.objects.filter(**args)
```

You can **also** (if you need a mix of `AND` and `OR`) use Django's [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

> Keyword argument queries – in filter(), etc. – are “AND”ed together. If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with OR statements), you can use Q objects.
>
> A Q object (django.db.models.Q) is an object used to encapsulate a
>   collection of keyword arguments. These keyword arguments are specified
>   as in “Field lookups” above.

You would have something like this instead of having all the `Q objects` within that filter:

```
** import Q from django
from *models import Item

#assuming your arguments are kwargs
final_q_expression = Q(kwargs[1])
for arg in kwargs[2:..]
    final_q_expression = final_q_expression & Q(arg);
result = Item.objects.filter(final_q_expression)
```

This is code I haven't run, it's out of the top of my head. Treat it as pseudo-code if you will.

Although, this doesn't answer why the ways you've tried don't quite work. Maybe it has to do with the **lookups that span relationships**, and the tables that are getting joined to get those values. I would suggest printing `yourQuerySet.query` to visualize the `raw SQL` that is being formed and that might help guide you as to why `.filter( Q() & Q())` is not working.